# Add delay to interpolated value in React Spring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-spring

I'm wondering if it's possible to add a delay to an interpolated value in react-spring. I want to have a single spring driving multiple animations, so I don't think `useChain` or `useTransition` will work here.

I have a spring like this:

```js
// This spring will drive multiple animations
const spring = useSpring({x: isActive ? 1 : 0})

// In my component
const opacity = spring.x.to([0, 0.5, 1, [0, 1, 1]) // want to add a delay here
const scale = spring.x.to([0, 0.5, 1, [0, 1, 1])
<animated.div style={{opacity, scale}} />
```

In the above example, I want the scale animation to conclude when the driving spring value reaches 0.5. However, I want the opacity animation to be delayed by 200ms, but still attached to the same spring. Is this possible, or do I need to use multiple springs?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to create a separate SpringValue for that (easily done by adding an additional `key` to your `useSpring` hook). This is because interpolations simply transform values, they don't interact with the animation of the value.